# Appending to large CSV overloads memory

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV with ~300k rows that I append a few thousand rows to every day. The problem is, the more I write to the CSV, the more memory gets eaten. I write to it by taking data from two lists, combining it into a dictionary and writing all that to a row (as below).

```
with open('mydata.csv', 'a') as csvfile:

    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=cols)

    for package, li in zip(my_data, my_list):
        
        row_data = {}
        data_to_append_to_row = li.get_text()
        
        try:
            row_data['description'] = package['description']
        except Exception as e:
            pass

        row_data["core_id"] = data_to_append_to_row
        
        await writer.writerow(row_data)
```

Every time more rows get added to the csv and I need to append to it (daily), the memory I use increases.

Comment: You build `row_data` but write `releases`? There is nothing in this code that would grow memory as the csv file grows. You are mixing a blocking io call (the writer) with `await` which can cause your program to bog down, but I don't see a memory thing.

Comment: Thanks - just updated the code to reflect that row_data is written, not releases. That's interesting, I'm unsure then because my memory usage increases only when the CSV file is large, so I had assumed it was being read into memory every time and that was slowing it down.

Comment: Why are you using `await`? There nothing consuming more memory here.

Comment: Since you open in "a" append mode, the file isn't written. And since the `for` releases the previous row data on each loop, there isn't anything to build up here. If this same program is reading that csv somewhere else - that's the problem - but this looks like a good way to fill the file. `my_data` and `my_list` aren't known here either, so can't really say how they are envolved.

Comment: As an aside, you could replace the entire for loop with `writer.writerows({"description":package.get("description", ""), "core_id":li.get_text()}
    for package, li in zip(my_data, my_list))`

Comment: In that other comment, I meant that in append mode the file isn't _read_ so its size doesn't matter.

Comment: Got it, thank you. You're right re using the await. I'll update both now and come back.